# Create own central templates

Tags: texlive, templates, ubuntu, linux

I worked with LaTeX for a short while and now I'd like to create my own templates for e.g. handouts. Here is a example for the beginning of my handout template:

```
\documentclass[12pt,german,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}
```

All of this templates should be in one folder somewhere on my file system e.g. `~/templates`. If I start a specific file I'd like to import one of these files with `\input{}`. I got the advice to use texmf-local for this because the LaTeX commands doesn't understand environment variables (I use Ubuntu Linux). Unfortunately I don't have any experience with that.

So how can I create a central folder for all my templates and input these files with e.g. `\input{handout}`? It would be cool if I only have to change one variable after moving the template folder to another place.

Comment: I put my `sty` personal file at `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/local/mymacros.sty` and then I can load it using `\usepackage{}`.

Comment: have you tried creating a directory `$HOME/texmf`, then running `texhash ~/texmf` whenever you add templates?

Comment: You don't need to run `texhash`. Just create `~/texmf/tex/latex/mytemplates/` or whatever and put your files there. TeX doesn't rely on the database to find files in your `TEXMFHOME` (`~/texmf`) but searches the relevant paths directly e.g. `~/texmf/bibtex/bib` for `.bib` files etc.

Comment: Does https://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#x1-360003.4.6 help?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: You should *hide* your templates in a class file to make it more robust and then follow the hints in [Where do I place my own .sty or .cls files, to make them available to all my .tex files?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1137) Would this answer your question so we could close this as a duplicate?

Comment: btw: there is a regulars table in Dresden. If you are still there, you can check it out.